# Choosing <> or "" for c++ include

Tags: c++

I am working with example code from Stroustrup's book(Programming: Principles and Practice using C++").I have downloaded std_lib_facilities.h from

```
http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h
```

When I try to compile on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc,I got this:

```
d19.cc:1:32: fatal error: std_lib_facilities.h: No such file or directory
 #include <std_lib_facilities.h>
```

Then I have doublechecked,file is in my directory.

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/cplus$ ls -l std_lib_facilities.h 
-rw-r----- 1 milenko milenko 5667 Jul  4 09:35 std_lib_facilities.h
```

I have changed <> to "" and works fine,but still lingers a question why do we use `<iostream>` and  `"std_lib_facilities.h"`

Comment: The include path - perhaps change <> to "

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include path - perhaps change <> to "